# How do I get a full color watermark in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, transparency, watermark

I have added a watermark to my Word document and it automatically fades the color. I would like it to show up in full color.

I did a Google search and tried everything I could find. I unchecked the 'washout' option. No joy. When everyone kept repeating the same thing, "goto **picture format-->Adjust** then change the transparency". I tried to do that but the transparency option doesn't show up there. I tried right clicking on the image and selecting **Format autoshape/picture...**. I see the brightness and contrast controls but not transparency.

Can anyone help?

Comment: "A watermark is an identifying image or pattern in paper that appears as various shades of lightness/darkness when viewed by transmitted light" perhaps WATERMARK is not what you are looking for.  What you are looking for is an overlapping image.. I think..  An unfaded watermark is not a watermark.

Comment: If the watermark with full color, how did you display the text in Page?

Answer (score -1):

### Watermarks in Word are in a Header. When you are in Print View you will not see headers (or footers) full strength

This is by design. The idea is that this material is not really on the page and you should not be distracted by it. Since Watermarks are in the header, this applies to them as well.

You will see this material full-strength in the printed document including pdf copies.

If you want it full-strength in Print View, you need to actually insert the image on each page, not as a Watermark, and not in a Header or Footer. This should only be done at the very end of your editing process because it is a real pain to edit. *I strongly urge against doing this. You will likely regret it.*

### If that does not address your problem, perhaps you want a simple image in the header rather than a Watermark.

You do not have to use the "Watermark" feature in Word to insert an image in a header. Putting the image in the header or footer, though, is the only reliable way of having it appear automatically on multiple pages. This is how the Watermark feature works but it also tags the image behind the scenes with the metadata that it is a Watermark. You do not need that metadata.

Rather than use the Watermark feature, you can simply edit your header(s) to include the image you want.

Here are parts of my chapter on Sections in Word dealing with Watermarks:

- [Watermarks in Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Watermarks)
- [Troubleshooting Watermarks](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Troubleshooting_Watermarks)

Keep in mind that each Section in a Word document will have up to three headers, independent of one another. If you have multiple sections, those headers can be linked to other previous sections or independent. So, this can be insertion of a single image in a single header or one insertion for each header in each section.

Comment: I have no idea why you were slammed for this.. this was my first thought.

Comment: Thank you for the support. I re-ordered my suggestions and observations. Perhaps that will make someone happier.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon - My downvote was due to the unnecessary links to the your own website.  You don't quote the information so the link to drive traffic to your website isn't necessary (IMO).

Comment: I understand your reasoning. The links were to supply additional background in case the questioner wants it. My website is non-commercial, not add-funded. Had I needed the information from the site to adequately answer the question, I would have quoted it. That would make this answer extend over multiple screens, though.